# Why doesn't src inside <picture> element load?

Tags: html, picture-element

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="images/me.webp">
  <img id="avatar" src="images/me.webp" alt="Me">
</picture>
```

When I use the `picture` element, the browser(chrome) doesn't load the image with the other resources. However, when I replace `<picture>` with only `<img>` element it works fine:

```
<img id="avatar" src="images/me.webp" alt="Me">
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you on?

Comment: @user5854648 chrome 67.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will load the me.webp image if the browser supports its. If not, the jpg image will be shown (which works). Chrome 67 supports webp format, so the only issue I can figure out is that me.webp is not in the images folder.

Comment: This also works: `<img id="avatar" src="images/me.webp" alt="Me">`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `<picture>` is used when you want multiple possible images to use in a responsive design. The `<img>` at the end is the fallback. It sounds like `images/me.webp` isn;'t working.

Unless you are really making use of `<picture>`, use `<img>`.

Comment: i am using version 70.0.3538.110 and i tested it. it is working fine. may be the version issue you have.